# Accumulate values into an array with Postgres

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, array, aggregate-filter

Currently I have this query:

```
select 
    sum(case when my_table.property_type = 'FLAT' then my_table.price else 0 end) as Flat_Current_Asking_Price,
    sum(case when my_table.property_type_mapped = 'SEMIDETACHED' then my_table.price else 0 end) as Semidetached_Current_Asking_Price
from 
    my_table;
```

So if `my_table` has the values:

```
property_type | price
--------------+-------
FLAT          | 5000
SEMIDETACHED  | 9000
FLAT          | 6000
```

the query will return:

```
Flat_Current_Asking_Price | Semidetached_Current_Asking_Price
--------------------------+-----------------------------------
11000                     | 9000
```

How can I replace the `sum` to accumulate the values into arrays to get?

```
Flat_Current_Asking_Price | Semidetached_Current_Asking_Price
--------------------------+-----------------------------------
{5000, 6000}              | {9000}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your PostggreSQL version is 9.4 or later use [`FILTER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) clause:

```
select
    array_agg(my_table.price) filter(where my_table.property_type = 'FLAT' ) as Flat_Current_Asking_Price,
    array_agg(my_table.price) filter(where my_table.property_type = 'SEMIDETACHED') as Semidetached_Current_Asking_Price
from 
    my_table;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the arrays, use `array_agg`, instead of `SUM`:

```
SELECT
    array_agg(case when my_table.property_type = 'FLAT'         then my_table.price end) as Flat_Current_Asking_Price,
    array_agg(case when my_table.property_type = 'SEMIDETACHED' then my_table.price end) as Semidetached_Current_Asking_Price
FROM 
    my_table;
```

```
flat_current_asking_price | semidetached_current_asking_price
:------------------------ | :--------------------------------
{5000,NULL,6000}          | {NULL,9000,NULL}
```

If you want to get rid of the nulls, use instead a smallish trick (array_to_string gets rid of them):

```
SELECT
    string_to_array(array_to_string(array_agg(case when my_table.property_type = 'FLAT'         then my_table.price end), '|'), '|') as Flat_Current_Asking_Price,
    string_to_array(array_to_string(array_agg(case when my_table.property_type = 'SEMIDETACHED' then my_table.price end), '|'), '|') as Semidetached_Current_Asking_Price
FROM 
    my_table;
```

```
flat_current_asking_price | semidetached_current_asking_price
:------------------------ | :--------------------------------
{5000,6000}               | {9000}
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=857f9f9aba56430b9d40e77ba321c45e)*

---

**addendum**

Per commment of Abelisto, you can also use `array_remove`:

```
SELECT
    array_remove(array_agg(case when my_table.property_type = 'FLAT'         then my_table.price end), NULL) as Flat_Current_Asking_Price,
    array_remove(array_agg(case when my_table.property_type = 'SEMIDETACHED' then my_table.price end), NULL) as Semidetached_Current_Asking_Price
FROM 
    my_table;
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=2850bb253062dabe4d333c76f2bd5584)*

Comment: BTW: `array_remove()` function is able to remove NULLs: `select array_remove(array[1,null,3], null);`